# How can I get the expander function to work with dynamic jQuery data?

Tags: jquery, function, expand, expander

Thanks for taking a look at this question. I am trying to get the jQuery expander function to work in my UI.

The problem is, it works when the data is hardcoded in the HTML but it does not work when data is dynamically placed by jQuery.

I have created 4 slides to better illustrate the issue (see below for images):

**SLIDE 1:** The UI that contains the small text I am trying to expand in each module shown.

**SLIDE 2:** The div structure set up for jQuery to populate date in realtime

**SLIDE 3:** Chrome Inspector showing the data dynamically held in memory (not in the HTML source)

**SLIDE 4:** The expander function works when I hardcode this in the HTML:

```
<div class="tags-hidden"><p>some data...</p></div>
```

Here is the origin of the expander function:
http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/

Many, many thanks for any help or advice you could offer. Here are the slides:

[image: Slide 1]

[image: Slide 2]

[image: Slide 3]

[image: Slide 4]

EDIT 1 -  Here is the new code based on your suggestion to use .live()... It doesn't seem to get called on click:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.div.tags-hidden p').live('click', function() {
    $('div.tags-hidden p').expander({
      slicePoint:       80,  // default is 100
      expandText:         '[...]', // default is 'read more...'
      collapseTimer:    5000, // re-collapses after 5 seconds; default is 0, so no re-collapsing
      userCollapseText: '[^]'  // default is '[collapse expanded text]'
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you jeed to use .live() for elements that are not displayed when the page is rendered.
 Take a look here http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I just added Edit 1 to my main post that has the new code using .live(). It doesn't seeem to work...

Comment: Oh, it's not an event function, but a styling function. The only solution I can think of is the server sending the code from slide 4  with the Ajax  data. Ugly, but works.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to re-wire the expander plugin after your content is loaded. If you are loading your content dynamically via ajax calls, for example, you will need to call `$('div.tags-hidden p').expander()` again after the ajax load is complete.

Comment: Chris thanks for the response. I was just wondering if you thought .live() could be the solution for this and if so how would implement it? Thanks again!