# How to apply jQuery expander after changing div contents dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a div with some content. jQuery expander is applied to it. After a while the contents of the div are changed via an ajax call. How can I apply the expander to the div again in the jquery .done()?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.expandable').expander({
    slicePoint: 200,
    preserveWords: true,
    widow: 4,
    expandText: 'continue reading',
    detailClass: 'expanderDetails',
    afterExpand: function(){
        $('#mybutton').click(); //simulate a different click.
    }
});
```

Contents of div.expandable are changed by an ajax request. Once than happens, I'm losing the 'Read More' functionality. I want to apply the expander effect back to the div on request.done(). How to achieve this? Just running this doesn't work:

```
$('div.expandable').expander();
```

Comment: Did you try it to put it in a function and call it everytime the change is done?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617547/how-can-i-get-jquery-live-and-expander-to-function-properly-together

Comment: That's the only relevant question I could find and unfortunately it wasn't helpful. Hence, the new question. There must be a super easy way to re-attach expander.

Comment: @FakeHeal - Yes, I'm calling it in the request.done() as this: $('div.expandable').expander();

Comment: Can anyone help please? I've lost quite a few hours on this!

Comment: Did you find a solution? (In my case I have to open different AJAX popup)

Answer (score 1):

First you should wrap your expander code into a function:

```
function initExpander() {
    $('div.expandable').expander({
        slicePoint: 200,
        preserveWords: true,
        widow: 4,
        expandText: 'continue reading',
        detailClass: 'expanderDetails',
        afterExpand: function(){
            $('#mybutton').click(); //simulate a different click.
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can use this function every time you need to initialize the expander, for example after the DOM load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initExpander();
});
```

Or right after the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/doajax',
    // .... your ajax request here
    success: function () {
         initExpander();
    }
});
```

If you are using done() with ajax, it's fine too:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/doajax',
    // .... your ajax request here
}).done(function () {
    initExpander();
});
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for this! In my case I have to open different AJAX retrieved content popups. If I add initExpander() in success: it will work for first popup only. Ideas?

Comment: Well it's pretty hard to imagine how it works in your case, ideally could you post a question and link it here then I can take a look?